# In Magento 1.9 How to display mini-cart in top menu?

Tags: php, ajax, magento

I am new to Magento 1.9. I have a custom theme. I need to display functional mini-cart in top menu. Right now I am not sure how to achieve this?

Comment: You probably could use google a bit more :-) Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841390/toggle-dropdown-mini-cart-when-product-added-to-basket. I am not sure it deals with your problems directly but possibly it can help you. Additionally it would be helpful to know what you tried and what did not work!

Comment: It discuss second step. It is about update mini-cart while I am at step one about how to show mini-cart in top menu.

Comment: mini cart is already implemented in rwd theme you can check there.

Comment: I mentioned already, I am using custom theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an step by step guide to my problem. Sharing link here for future reference.

http://dltr.org/blog/magento/118/Magento-add-sidebar-mini-cart-on-the-header

this header mini-cart depends on sidebar mini cart, make sure it's active at:
magento admin / system / configuration / Sales / Checkout / Shopping Cart Sidebar
Select "YES" for Display Shopping Cart Sidebar.

Add below code inside  on checkout.xml:

Path: app\design\frontend\your-package\your-template\layout\checkout.xml

```
<reference name="header">
    <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_cartheader" template="checkout/cart/cartheader.phtml" before="-">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/cartheader/default.phtml</template></action>
      <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/cartheader/default.phtml</template></action>
      <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/cartheader/default.phtml</template></action>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_cartheader.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
            <label>Shopping Cart Cartheader Extra Actions</label>
        </block>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Create new file cartheader.phtml under checkout/cart as below and add the below code in it:

Path: app\design\frontend\your-package\your-template\template\checkout\cart\cartheader.phtml

```
<div class="mini-cart-layer">
    <?php if ($this->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()):?>
        <div class="top-cart">
            <?php $_cartQty = $this->getSummaryCount() ?>
            <?php if ($_cartQty > 0): ?>
                <?php $_myCart = $this->__('Shopping Cart (%s items)', $_cartQty) ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php $_myCart = $this->__('Shopping Cart (0 item)') ?>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?php if ($this->getIsLinkMode() || !$this->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()):?>
                <div class="block-title no-items">
                    <ul class="links cart-link">
                        <li ><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart'); ?>" rel="nofollow"><?php echo $_myCart ?></a>  </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            <?php else:?>
                <div class="block-title<?php if(!$_cartQty) { echo (' no-items'); } ?>">
                    <span id="cartHeader"><?php echo $_myCart ?></span>
                </div>
                <div id="topCartContent" class="block-content" style="display:none">
                    <div class="inner-wrapper"><?php /*extra div to smooth slideUp and slideDown*/ ?>
                        <?php $_items = $this->getRecentItems() ?>
                        <?php if(count($_items)): ?>
                            <p class="block-subtitle">
                                <span onclick="toggleTopCart();" class="close-btn"><?php echo $this->__('Close'); ?></span>
                                <?php echo $this->__('Recently added item(s)') ?>
                            </p>
                            <ol id="mini-cart" class="mini-products-list">
                                <?php foreach($_items as $_item): ?>
                                    <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ol>
                            <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('mini-cart', 'none-recursive')</script>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <p class="block-subtitle">
                                <span onclick="toggleTopCart()" class="close-btn"><?php echo $this->__('Close'); ?></span>
                                    <?php echo $this->__('Recently added item(s)') ?>
                            </p>
                            <p class="cart-empty">
                                <?php echo $this->__('You have no items in your shopping cart.') ?>
                            </p>
                        <?php endif ?>
                        <?php if($_cartQty && $this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout()): ?>
                            <div class="actions">
                                <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart'); ?>" rel="nofollow"><?php echo $this->__('Go to Shopping Cart') ?></a>
                                <button class="button" type="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?></span></span></button>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endif;?>
        </div>
    <?php endif;?>
</div>
```

Now create new file default.phtml under checkout/cart/cartheader as below and add the following code:

Path:app\design\frontend\your-package\your-template\template\checkout\cart\cartheader\default.phtml

```
<?php
$_item = $this->getItem();
$isVisibleProduct = $_item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
//$canApplyMsrp =   Mage::helper('catalog')->canApplyMsrp($_item->getProduct(),     Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Msrp_Type::TYPE_BEFORE_ORDER_CONFIRM    );
?>
<li class="item">
    <?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl()?>" title="<?php echo     $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(50, 50)->setWatermarkSize('30x10'); ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>" /></a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(50, 50)->setWatermarkSize('30x10'); ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>" /></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="product-details">
        <p class="product-name">
            <?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>">
            <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>
            <?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()): ?>
                </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </p>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getDeleteUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?>" onclick="return confirm('<?php echo $this->__('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?') ?>');" class="top-btn-remove">
            <?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?>
        </a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Open template page/html/header.phtml, and add following code at bottom or suitable place

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cart_cartheader') ?>
```

Now we need Javascript to slide mini cart up and down (slide toggle). To achieve that toggle effect add the following code on new javascript file named cf.js

Path: skin\frontend\your-package\your-template\js\cf.js

```
/**

function slideUp()
{
    jQuery('#topCartContent:visible').slideUp(1000);
    jQuery('.mini-cart-layer').addClass('mini-cart-layer-up');
    jQuery('.mini-cart-layer').removeClass('mini-cart-layer-down');
}

function slideDown()
{
    jQuery('#topCartContent:hidden').slideDown(1000);
    /*startTimer()*/ /* optional*/
    jQuery('.mini-cart-layer').addClass('mini-cart-layer-down');
    jQuery('.mini-cart-layer').removeClass('mini-cart-layer-up');
}

function toggleTopCart()
{
if(jQuery('#topCartContent').is(':visible'))
    {
        slideUp();
    } else {
        slideDown();
    }
}

var timer;
function startTimer()
{
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        slideUp();
    }, 5000);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.mini-cart-layer .top-cart .block-title #cartHeader').click(function(){
        toggleTopCart();
    });

    jQuery('.mini-cart-layer .top-cart .block-title         #cartHeader').mouseover(function(){
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }).mouseout(function(){
        startTimer();
    });

    jQuery("#topCartContent").mouseover(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }).mouseout(function(){
        startTimer();
    });
});
```

To include above file on the  section add the below line on page.xml after jquery inclusion.

Path: app\design\frontend\your-package\your-template\layout\page.xml

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.js</name><params/></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/cf.js</name><params/></action>
```

Now time for CSS for the tabs: You need to modify as your need and replace images.

```
/*---*/
.clear:after {
clear: both;
content: ".";
display: block;
height: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}
div.mini-cart-layer {
background: url("../images/view_shopping_cart.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
height: 26px;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 9px;
width: 165px;
z-index: 99;
}
.top-cart .top-btn-remove {
background: url("../images/btn_remove.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
display: block;
font-size: 11px;
height: 15px;
line-height: 11px;
margin: 0 0 3px;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}
div.mini-cart-layer-up{}
div.mini-cart-layer-down{background-position: 0 bottom;}
.mini-cart-layer span#cartHeader {
display: block;
height: 26px;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: left;
text-indent: -99999px;
width: 165px;
}
.top-cart {
float: left;
position: relative;
}
.top-cart .block-title {
white-space: nowrap;
cursor: pointer;
}
.top-cart .block-title.expanded {
background-position: 0 3px !important;
}
.top-cart .block-title.expanded span {
background-position: 100% -126px !important;
}
.top-cart .block-content {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FDFDFD;
font-size: 11px;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
text-align: left;
top: 20px;
width: 267px;
}
.top-cart .block-content ol {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none outside none;
}
.top-cart .inner-wrapper {
border: 4px solid #DB4C6A;
}
.top-cart .block-content .block-subtitle {
background: #DB4C6A;
font-size: 10px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #fff;
line-height: 12px;
padding: 3px 10px 4px;
}
.top-cart .block-content .block-subtitle .close-btn {
float: right;
width: 13px;
height: 0;
padding-top: 12px;
text-align: left;
overflow: hidden;
cursor: pointer;
background: url(../images/btn_remove.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}
.top-cart .cart-empty .close-btn {
float: right;
width: 13px;
height: 0;
padding-top: 12px;
text-align: left;
overflow: hidden;
cursor: pointer;
background: url(../images/btn_remove.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}
.top-cart .cart-empty {
padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
color: #666;
}
.top-cart .block-content .item {
padding: 8px 5px 8px 11px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
margin: 0 5px;
}
.top-cart .block-content .last {
border-bottom: none;  
}
.top-cart .block-content .item .product-name {
font-size: 11px;
height: 30px;
line-height: 14px;
margin: 0 0 5px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.top-cart .block-content .item .product-name a {
font-size: 11px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #444;
}
.top-cart .block-content table {
margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}
.top-cart .block-content table th {
padding: 1px 8px;
color: #8f8f8f;
text-align: right;
}
.top-cart .block-content table td {
text-align: left;
padding: 1px 0;
}
.top-cart .block-content .subtotal {
padding: 2px 5px;
text-align: center;
color: #666;
}
.top-cart .actions {
background-color: #DB4C6A;
color: #FFFFFF;
padding: 5px 11px;
text-align: right;
z-index: 999;
}
.top-cart .actions a {
float: left;
line-height: 23px;
}
.top-cart .actions button {
float: none;
color: #FFF;
padding-top: 3px;
}
div.top-cart {
float: none;
}
div.top-cart .block-title {
color: #000000;
display: block;
float: none;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 0;
}
div.top-cart .block-content {
top: 26px;
}
div.top-cart .block-content ol li {
display: block;
float: none;
}
/*===*/
```

Comment: This really helpful, I used this.